# Magento multistore iframe issue

Tags: php, magento, iframe, magento-1.7

In my magento multi-store website, the site loads normally.

When selecting any other link in that site, that loads in the iframe.

I was totally stuck on it.

Somebody help me to remove the loading of the site in iframe.

Comment: Can you show me some example site ? i have no idea how this work.

Comment: e-zoffer.com is a primary site. pageplus123.com is a multistore site.

Comment: Can you give a litle more brief on ur doubt?? I have checked the above links.. I didnt get ur problem there. So it will be helpful if u can explain it with screenshots or more brief...